# How to cast a 1-d IntTensor to int in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

How do I convert a 1-D IntTensor to an integer? This:

```
IntTensor.int()
```

Gives an error:

```
KeyError: Variable containing:
 423
[torch.IntTensor of size 1]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get value of a tensor in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727372/how-do-i-get-value-of-a-tensor-in-pytorch)

Comment: Could you update the accepted answer?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use:

`print(dictionary[IntTensor.data[0]])`

The key you're using is an object of type `autograd.Variable`.
`.data` gives the tensor and the index `0` can be used to access the element.

Answer (score 100):

The simplest and cleanest method I know:

```
IntTensor.item()
```

> Returns the value of this tensor as a standard Python number. This only works for tensors with one element. For other cases, see `tolist`.

- [PyTorch Docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.item)

Comment: This is by far the best answer and should be marked as accepted one.