# How do I get the value of a tensor in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Printing a tensor `x` gives:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([3])
>>> print(x)
tensor([3])
```

Indexing `x.data` gives:

```
>>> x.data[0]
tensor(3)
```

How do I get just a regular non-tensor value `3`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cast a 1-d IntTensor to int in Pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588682/how-to-cast-a-1-d-inttensor-to-int-in-pytorch)

Answer (score 238, accepted):

You can use [`x.item()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html) to get a Python number from a `Tensor` that has one element.

Comment: What if there were more than one item in our tensor? It throws an error when I have a tensor with 2 or more elements.

Answer (score 49):

### To get a value from single element tensor `x.item()` works always:

*Example* : **Single element tensor on CPU**

```py
x = torch.tensor([3])
x.item()
```

Output:

```
3
```

*Example* : **Single element tensor on CPU with AD**

```
x = torch.tensor([3.], requires_grad=True)
x.item()
```

Output:

```
3.0
```

NOTE: We needed to use floating point arithmetic for AD

*Example* : **Single element tensor on CUDA**

```py
x = torch.tensor([3], device='cuda')
x.item()
```

Output:

```
3
```

*Example* : **Single element tensor on CUDA with AD**

```py
x = torch.tensor([3.], device='cuda', requires_grad=True)
x.item()
```

Output:

```
3.0
```

*Example* : **Single element tensor on CUDA with AD again**

```py
x = torch.ones((1,1), device='cuda', requires_grad=True)
x.item()
```

Output:

```
1.0
```

### To get a value from non single element tensor we have to be careful:

The next example will show that PyTorch tensor residing on CPU shares the same storage as numpy array `na`

*Example*: **Shared storage**

```
import torch
a = torch.ones((1,2))
print(a)
na = a.numpy()
na[0][0]=10
print(na)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1., 1.]])
[[10.  1.]]
tensor([[10.,  1.]])
```

*Example*: **Eliminate effect of shared storage, copy numpy array first**

To avoid the effect of shared storage we need to `copy()` the numpy array `na` to a new numpy array `nac`. Numpy `copy()` method creates the new separate storage.

```py
import torch
a = torch.ones((1,2))
print(a)
na = a.numpy()
nac = na.copy()
nac[0][0]=10
​print(nac)
print(na)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1., 1.]])
[[10.  1.]]
[[1. 1.]]
tensor([[1., 1.]])
```

Now, just the `nac` numpy array will be altered with the line `nac[0][0]=10`, `na` and `a` will remain as is.

*Example*: **CPU tensor `requires_grad=True`**

```py
import torch
a = torch.ones((1,2), requires_grad=True)
print(a)
na = a.detach().numpy()
na[0][0]=10
print(na)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1., 1.]], requires_grad=True)
[[10.  1.]]
tensor([[10.,  1.]], requires_grad=True)
```

In here we call:

```py
na = a.numpy()
```

This would cause: `RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead.`, because tensors that `require_grad=True` are recorded by PyTorch AD.

This is why we need to `detach()` them first before converting using `numpy()`.

*Example*: **CUDA tensor `requires_grad=False`**

```py
a = torch.ones((1,2), device='cuda')
print(a)
na = a.to('cpu').numpy()
na[0][0]=10
print(na)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1., 1.]], device='cuda:0')
[[10.  1.]]
tensor([[1., 1.]], device='cuda:0')
```

​
In here we just don't convert the CUDA tensor to CPU. There is no effect of shared storage here.

*Example*: **CUDA tensor `requires_grad=True`**

```py
a = torch.ones((1,2), device='cuda', requires_grad=True)
print(a)
na = a.detach().to('cpu').numpy()
na[0][0]=10
​print(na)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1., 1.]], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
[[10.  1.]]
tensor([[1., 1.]], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
```

Without `detach()` method the error `RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead.` will be set.

Without `.to('cpu')` method `TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.` will be set.

Answer (score 30):

Convert tensor to numpy:

```
x.numpy()[0]
```

Comment: `x.item()` as @Vimal Thilak wrote is likely the most pythonic way assuming (as in your example) that the tensor has one element. This approach is best by avoiding additional conversion between types.

Comment: If `x` is on the GPU, this will fail. Best to do `x[0].item()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `x.cpu().detach().numpy()` to get a Python array from a tensor that has one element and then you can get a number from this array