# Get Pytorch - tensor values as a integer in python

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I have my output of my torch tensor which looks like below

(coordinate of a bounding box in object detection)

```
[tensor(299., device='cuda:0'), tensor(272., device='cuda:0'), tensor(327., device='cuda:0'), tensor(350., device='cuda:0')]
```

I wanted to extract each of the tensor value as an int in the form of **minx,miny,maxx,maxy** 
so that I can pass it to a shapely function in the below form

```
from shapely.geometry import box
minx,miny,maxx,maxy=1,2,3,4
b = box(minx,miny,maxx,maxy)
```

What's the best way to do it? by avoiding, Cuda enabled or not or other exceptions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get value of a tensor in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727372/how-do-i-get-value-of-a-tensor-in-pytorch)

Answer (score 2):

```
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = [int(t.item()) for t in tensors]
```

where `tensors` is the list of tensors.