# How do I get the float value of a 1x1 EagerTensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 1x1 EagerTensor object that I'm trying to convert to a single float value. i.e.

tf.Tensor([[-0.04473801]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32) -> -0.04473801

There seemed to be a simple answer that I've used on other tensors in the past - just use the item() method [a la this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727372/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-tensor-in-pytorch) However, when I try to use the .item() method on an EagerTensor object, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'item'
```

Why is this happening? Do EagerTensors not have the item() method? One workaround I've found is using `float(tensor_variable.numpy()[0])`, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use squeeze to remove dimensions of size 1:

```py
import tensorflow as tf


t = tf.constant([[-0.04473801]])
tf.squeeze(t).numpy()
>>> -0.04473801
```